# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type every time i use multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]I would like to return json data from my controller but the error i get is "a circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type".

So far i can only return data from only one table called "Projects" but when i try to include my look up table "ProjectTypes" i get the circular reference. if there is a way to return data of Projects and its correct Project Type please kindly assist me.

```
    public JsonResult getProjects()
    {
        bool proxyCreation = dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
        try
        {
            //set ProxyCreation to false
            dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            var projects = dc.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectType);

            return Json(projects.ToList(), "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            //restore ProxyCreation to its original state
            dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreation;
        }
    }
```

Below are my Project and Project Type Class

```
public partial class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ProjectedEndDate { get; set; }
        public int ProjectTypeID { get; set; }

        public virtual ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class ProjectType
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ProjectType()
        {
            this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }

        public int ProjectTypeID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

the result i was expecting to get is

[{"ProjectID":0,"Description":"Watch Anime","StartDate":"/Date(1569016800000)/","EndDate":null,"ProjectedEndDate":"/Date(1569016800000)/","ProjectType":Maintainance,"ProjectType":null},{"ProjectID":1,"Description":"Grass Cutting","StartDate":"/Date(1569362400000)/","EndDate":null,"ProjectedEndDate":"/Date(1569448800000)/","ProjectType":Maintainance,"ProjectType":null}]

or a combiened json result of both Project and ProjectTypes Table but the actual result i get is an error message as stated above.

Comment: I guess your data structure is indeed a recursive structure, e.g. a Project contains a pointer to a Project. Please show the declaration of your classes for Project and ProjectType.

Comment: i have re updated my question including the entity framework classes i am using.

Comment: Hm, you posted only an excerpt, but it seems you have indeed a circular reference. A project contains a projecttype, and a projecttype contains a list of projects?

Answer (score 0):

There is an endless loop where the `ProjectType` navigation property of the `Project` object points to its related `ProjectType` object, whose `Projects` navigation property includes the `Project` object and so on.

There is no way to disable this behavior, so the best solution for avoiding endless loops of related data is to set the navigation property to null before it reaches the JSON serializer to create a dynamic type so that there are no null values included in the result, which is the approach that I have taken in the sample below:

```cs
    public JsonResult getProjects()
    {
            // Code omitted
            var projects = dc.Projects.Include(p => p.ProjectType)
                 .Select(p => new {
                     Id = p.Id,
                     ProjectType = new {
                         Id = p.ProjectType.Id,
                     }
                 });

            return Json(projects.ToList(), "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

The second option: (Although, this just hides the problem and doesn't actually solve it.)

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
     opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```